# ajax if condition not working properly,always working else part

Tags: javascript, ajax

```js
var name=document.getElementById('txtUserName').value;
$.ajax({
    url:"loginAjax.php",
    type:"POST",
    data:({username: name}),
    success:function(data)
    {
        alert(data);
        if(data == 'Latelogin'){
            ret =  true;
            alert(ret);
        }
        else{
            ret = false;
            alert(ret);
        }
    }
});
```

The above code, I know the value of data is latelogin but always else part is working. I don't know why. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Case is important. Maybe service returns 'latelogin' all lowercase, but you are checking it capitalized.

Comment: Use `data.toLowerCase() == 'latelogin'` to avoid case issues.

Comment: hai,@MarioCianciolo, service returns Latelogin only,i checked very well

Comment: can you please `console.log(data)` and get it to us, just to make sure, instead of beating about the bush

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following:

```
var name=document.getElementById('txtUserName').value;
$.ajax({
    url:"loginAjax.php",
    type:"POST",
    data:({username: name}),
    success:function(data)
    jsdata = data.d;
    console.log(jsdata);
    {
        //alert(data);
        if(jsdata == 'Latelogin'){
            ret =  true;
            alert(ret);
        }
        else{
            ret = false;
            alert(ret);
        }
    }
});
```